# Answers not showing on profiles on mobile site.

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers

For some reason, answers are not displaying on mine or other's profiles on the mobile site. See the picture below.

[image]

Comment: I too observe the same issue from a few hours today. I think they are doing many changes related to responsive activity page and it should be fixed soon.

Comment: This has now been posted on the main meta:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374104/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been fixed

> answer titles blank?
> sorry for the regression
> back to normal now